# Use MATLAB to randomly pair two variables

Tags: matlab, variables, random

I am looking to use MATLAB to randomly assign numbers to a list of variables.  The variables represent video clips being used in an experiment.  I want to randomize the order of the clips, so I want to pair each clip with, for example, numbers 1-15, without repetition.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generate a random number in a certain range in MATLAB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077800/generate-a-random-number-in-a-certain-range-in-matlab)

Comment: @AnderBiguri I think the "without repetition" bit indicates `randperm` instead.

Comment: @beaker you are right. Most likely duplicate also. Flag it if possible, or answer it else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you put your clips into an array, you can use [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) to shuffle them. For example:

```
clips = [clip1, clip2, ..., clip15]
shuffle = randperm(length(clips))
randomized_clips = clips(shuffle)
```