# Adding noise signal to data encoding

Tags: matlab

I am following [this](http://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/41320-line-coding--manchester--unipolar-and-polar-rz--unipolar-nrz) example code. I want to add a random noise signal with 2 values per bit. How can I solve that?

The Code looks like:

```
bits =[1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0];
bitrate = 1; % bits per second

figure;
[t,s] = pnrz(bits,bitrate);
plot(t,s,'LineWidth',3);
axis([0 t(end) -1.1 1.1])
grid on;
title(['Polar NRZ: [' num2str(bits) ']']);
T = length(bits)/bitrate; % full time of bit sequence
n = 200;
N = n*length(bits);
dt = T/N;
t = 0:dt:T;
x = zeros(1,length(t)); % output signal
for i = 0:length(bits)-1
    if bits(i+1) == 1
        x(i*n+1:(i+1)*n) = 1;
    else
        x(i*n+1:(i+1)*n) = -1;
    end
end
```

Comment: The noise, you are adding, to which variable ?

Answer (score 0):

if I well understood your question, you can use the random function :

> random1or0 = randi(2)-1;

So `randi` will generate a random integer (in uniformly distributed manner) between 1 and 2, then subtracts  1 to get `0` or `1`.

You can relate to this question [Generate a random number in a certain range in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077800/generate-a-random-number-in-a-certain-range-in-matlab) for more details about random numbers in matlab.

Comment: yes it's right, but i want to know how to add 2 values per bit as noise signal?

Comment: `x(i*n+1:(i+1)*n) = (1+ random1or0) % 2;` and that's it. a noise is just random 0 or 1 added to the output, but if you want more details you have to read about noise in signals ...

Comment: `x(i*n+1:(i+1)*n) = (1+ random1or0) % 2;` is another solution @Sanap

Comment: @Sanap does this answer your question ? can you please explain what you mean by `how to add 2 values per bit` ? to add to which variable ?