# Random 3D matrix with decimal numbers

Tags: matlab, matrix, random

I want to create a 3D matrix of dimensions 681x711x29 with values between -0.3 and 0.3.

```
W=randi([-0.3, 0.3],681,711,29);
```

It gives the error:

```
First input must be a positive scalar integer value IMAX, or two integer values [IMIN IMAX] with IMIN less than or equal to IMAX.
```

I think it doesn't work because they're decimal numbers. **How do I make a 3D matrix with random decimal numbers between -0.3 and 0.3?**

Comment: Check the `randi` function. It returns random **integers** so it's not appropriate for what you need.

Comment: `rand` should be better. Try W = rand(681,711,29)*(0.3 - (-0.3)) - 0.3;

Comment: specify better what you want: real numbers between -0.3 and 0.3, or rational numbers with a fixed number of decimal places? What is a "decimal number" for you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generate a random number in a certain range in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077800/generate-a-random-number-in-a-certain-range-in-matlab)

Comment: Are you wanting numbers *uniformly distributed* on the interval [-0.3, 0.3]?  If so, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53613584/8239061) is good.  If not, please specify how you'd like the numbers distributed on that interval.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you need the `rand` function and not the `randi` function. `rand` will return a matrix with random numbers between 0 and 1. You can then transform it to the [-0.3 0.3] interval using the following formula.

```
W = -0.3 + (0.3-(-0.3))*rand(681,711,29);
```

or generally for an interval [`a`, `b`]

```
W = a + (b-a)*rand(m,n,...);
```