# Generating random numbers rounded to hundredths place in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, random

I am trying to generate random numbers from 0.1 - 0.7.

My current code is close to what I need, but is giving me numbers lower than 0.1:

```
frameDur1 = roundn((((7)*rand(1))/10), -2);
```

If you have suggestions on another/easier function I could use, that would be appreciated as well.

Thanks in advance!

*Don't believe this question is a duplicate, but thanks to Ali Rokni for the answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892375/matlab-generate-random-numbers?rq=1

Comment: See: [Random Numbers Within a Specific Range](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/floating-point-numbers-within-specific-range.html) from the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rand` generate uniformly distributed random numbers between (0,1). 
Your range size is

```
0.7 - 0.1 = 0.6 % max - min
```

First you should change the range to (0, 0.6). And then you add the minimum for changing the offset.

Therefore ultimately you have

```
0.1 + (0.7 - 0.1) * rand
```

Generally speaking assuming your desired range is (min, max)

```
min + (max - min) * rand
```